# Fully supporting uft8 in PHP - security issues?

Tags: php, utf-8

After going through many examples in this site, I have now made my website fully uft8 compliant. However, the [webcollab.sourceforge.io](https://webcollab.sourceforge.io/unicode.html) says,

> Overly long UTF-8 sequences and UTF-16 surrogates are a serious
>   security threat. Validation of input data is very important. An
>   algorithm using preg_replace() is given below, and is used in current
>   versions of WebCollab.

This is one part I have not done. Could anyone help me to understand how 
 UTF-8 sequences can cause a security issue?

Comment: You should really put some effort into googling... https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/are-there-any-security-bugs-with-utf-8

Comment: and there are millions of other results in google as well

Comment: @AlexKarshin this looks like a duplicate of that question to me too